# Datetime in the Relationship payload isn't deserialized correctly

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Background.

I'm storing User and Product nodes and I want to be able to record a date for each time that user purchases a product. When the results are being return the Purchased date is coming back as DateTime.Min but if I query Neo4j through the console I can see the dates are being stored as "2013-02-16T08:31:54.8604715+00:00"

The query I'm using to return the relationship payload is:

```
graphClient
.RootNode
.In < RootNode >(sourceTypeKeyToRoot)
.OutE<TData>(TypeKeyRelatingNodes())
.ToList();
```

TData is a simple class

```
public class PayLoad
{
   public DateTime Purchased { get; set; }
}
```

I get the same result if I use the Cypher queries as well.

Comment: It ended up being an issue with the TypeKey and I needed to use a DateTimeOffset rather than DateTime in the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a supported type, because we can't roundtrip it via Neo4j properly.

You should use `DateTimeOffset` instead.

You should receive an exception if you try to use `DateTime`, for any builds since 1.0.0.174 or so:

http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/d4118523780ee5dcacbe2f57b4f40ee6b90d6500/Neo4jClient/Deserializer/CommonDeserializerMethods.cs?at=default#cl-109

http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/commits/fa5bedfa60cb

Comment: I'm glad there is no ambiguity with dates here. Neo4jClient is awesome - thank you!

Comment: You might find this extension useful [http://www.blueprint41.com/](http://www.blueprint41.com/). Which also have different type conversion. So you won't need to worry about serializing.